# VS debugger won't step into XML deserializer constructor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, xml-deserialization, step-into

**Background**

I have a class that serializes to an XML file so users can change some startup settings. The class has an enum and I want the deserializer to accept either the name or int value as valid.

```
protected MyClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
  // want to Step Into  right here
  try {
    logLevel = (Logger.Level)info.GetValue("LogLevel", typeof(Logger.Level));
  }
  catch(Exception) {
    logLevel = (Logger.Level)info.GetValue("LogLevel", typeof(Int32));
  }
  …
```

It's not working, the XML deserialize() still throws an exception complaining than '0' or '1' etc. is not a valid value for that type. So naturally I try to debug via *Step Into* (F11) the line `MyClass mc = (MyClass)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(filepath);`

***Step Into***  **Not Going to Expected Code**

But the next line Visual Studio jumps to is the beginning of the class' *default* constructor MyClass(), instead of MyClass(SerializationInfo, StreamingContext) !!

So I F11 through that constructor (it assigns default values that have nothing to do with the XML file and as far as I know should not have been called at all) and when it jumps out of the constructor I land at the exception as before—apparently without ever having run through the deserialization code I wrote.

I even tried putting a `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch()` or `.Break()` at the beginning of the code I want to debug through, and Visual Studio 2010 just ignores it.

Is there something about deserialization constructors that Visual Studio can't or won't trace through them, or what's the deal?

Comment: Can you post a little more code?  What exception are you getting?

Comment: Have you made sure that you have set the debugger to debug both NATIVE and MANAGED code? From my experience, whenever the debugger jumps over source code that I want to step into, it is because one of those options are not set.